# How can I create an alphanumeric Regex for all languages?

Tags: regex, unicode, language-agnostic, non-english

I had this problem today:

This regex matches only English: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

If I need support for any language in this world, what regex should I write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use character class shorthands and a Unicode aware regex engine you can do that. The `\w` class matches "word characters" (letters, digits, and underscores).

Beware of some regex flavors that don't do this so well: JavaScript uses ASCII for `\d` (digits) and `\w`, but Unicode for `\s` (whitespace). XML does it the other way around.

Comment: This depends highly on which language/regex syntax you're using. `[[:alpha:]]` is probably more standard.

Comment: And if i don't want digits?

Comment: \w does not support international letters eg. Günther

Answer (score 7):

Alphabet/Letter: `\p{L}`

Number: `\p{N}`

So for alphnum match for all languages, you can use: `[\p{L}\p{N}]+`

I was looking for a way to replace all non-alphanum chars for all languages with a space in JS and ended up using the following way to do it:

```
const regexForNonAlphaNum = new RegExp(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/ug);
someText.replace(regexForNonAlphaNum, " ");
```

Here as it is JS, we need to add u at end to make the regex unicode aware and g stands for global as I wanted match all instances and not just a single instance.

References:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/regex-one-pattern-rule-them-all-find-bring-darkness-bind-carranza/?trackingId=U6tRte%2BzTAG6O4AA3CrFmA%3D%3D

https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Regex supporting most languages

**^[A-zÀ-Ÿ\d-]*$**

Answer (score 0):

The regex below is the only one worked for me:

```
"\\p{LD}+" ==> LD means any letter or digit.
```

If you want to clean your text from any non alphanumeric characters you can use the following:

```
text.replaceAll("\\P{LD}+", "");//Note P is capital.
```