# How to judge the characters of non-language characters?

Tags: erlang, elixir

My title may be misunderstood, I describe it:

- Can be Chinese/Japanese or any other country's language, such as `你好` or `こんにちは`
- Can be English letters, `A-Z` or `a-z`
- Can't be a symbol, such as `!` or `!`,`,` or `,`
- Can't be special characters such as Emoji or other symbols

Can it be judged by the binary byte number of elixir, or by Unicode?

Comment: In POSIX  compliant regexp there is a `:punct:` label - see the table here https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html but I doubt it is implemented in Elixir yet. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692540/how-can-i-create-an-alphanumeric-regex-for-all-languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you want to check if a given string contains Chinese/Japanese characters, or alphabetical characters. but not punctuation or emoji?

For the Asian characters you can use the [CJK range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block)) from Unicode, which might close enough. You can always [check more ranges](https://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php) for languages you want to (dis)allow.

So the first step would be to check if a given code point is in the [CJK range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block))(s):

```
  def is_in_range?(cp) do
    ranges = [
      {"\u4E00", "\u9FEF"},
      {"\u3400", "\u4DBF"},
      {"\u20000", "\u2A6DF"},
      {"\u2A700", "\u2B73F"},
      {"\u2B740", "\u2B81F"},
      {"\u2B820", "\u2CEAF"},
      {"\u2CEB0", "\u2EBEF"},
      {"\u3007", "\u3007"}
    ]

    # Check if the codepoint is any of the ranges above.
    ranges
    |> Enum.map(fn {s, e} ->
      cp >= s and cp <= e
    end)
    |> Enum.any?()
  end
```

If we have that function, we can check for any given string if it contains any of these characters:

```
  def contains_cjk(str) do
    str |> String.codepoints() |> Enum.map(&is_in_range?/1) |> Enum.any?()
  end
```

If you want to compare alpha characters you can use a regular regex, or just add the range from A-Z, and a-z (`\u0061` to `\u007A`, and `\u0041` to `\u005A`). For example, your second string (`こんにちは`) its first code point is in the "Hiragana" code block. You could add the range (`\u3040` to `\u309F`) to also allow these characters. A listing of blocks can be found [here](https://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php).

A note on performance is in place here. This code is not linear, as for `n` characters it will do `#amount_of_chars_in_range` comparisons.